# can't get value from another table in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

My problem is that I can't get the second table that I use from database with codeigniter

**MODEL**

```
public function ambil($id = FALSE){
    if($id===FALSE){
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM artikel,kategori WHERE artikel.id_kategori = kategori.id_kategori');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    $query = $this->db->get_where('artikel',array('id'=>$id));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function edit($id){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('judul', 'judul', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('konten','konten','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_kategori','id_kategori','required');

        if($this->form_validation->run()===false){
            $data['artikel'] = $this->m_daftar->ambil($id);
            $data['kategori'] = $this->m_daftar->get_kategori();
            $this->load->view('_atas');
            $this->load->view('v_daftar_edit',$data);
            $this->load->view('_bawah');
        }else{
            $this->m_daftar->update($id);
            redirect('/daftar','refresh');
        }
    }
```

**VIEW**: I need a value from "kategori"

```
<select name="id_kategori" id="id_kategori" class="form-control">
<option selected>kategori</option>
    <?php foreach($artikel as $item){
        echo '<option value='.$item['id_kategori'].'>'.$item['kategori'].'</option>';
    }?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Your SQL isn't correct - you need to look up how to do JOINS properly.

Answer (score 0):

Write another function name as **get_kategori($id)** :
MODEL:

```
public function get_kategori($id){
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM kategori WHERE id = '.$id.'');
        return $query->row_array();
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function edit($id){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('judul', 'judul', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('konten','konten','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_kategori','id_kategori','required');

        if($this->form_validation->run()===false){
            $data['artikel'] = $this->m_daftar->ambil($id);
            $data['kategori'] = $this->m_daftar->get_kategori($id);//Modified param
            $this->load->view('_atas');
            $this->load->view('v_daftar_edit',$data);
            $this->load->view('_bawah');
        }else{
            $this->m_daftar->update($id);
            redirect('/daftar','refresh');
        }
    }
```

Comment: im sorry, but i need to show the "kategori" column not the id itself, it's like the 'name' of its value.

Comment: No, im need to get "name_kategori" inside "kategori" database table

Comment: $data['kategori'] = $this->m_daftar->get_kategori($id);
echo "<pre>";print_r($data['kategori']);exit();

Comment: send what you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure maybe you need this:

```
<select name="id_kategori" id="id_kategori" class="form-control">
<option selected>kategori</option>
    <?php foreach($kategori as $item){ <--edit
        echo '<option value='.$item['id_kategori'].'>'.$item['kategori'].'</option>';
    }?>
    </select>
```